# Oracle query to group multi level many to many relationships into independent groups

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, many-to-many, hierarchy

BASED on the multi level MANY TO MANY dependency on student & subject cross reference, how to form a ORACLE sql/plsql query to GROUP the Student_Subject table so that groups are independent & exclusive as following? I have 519 rows in actual table. I am looking for a performant solution

Example Source table :

[image]

Expected Target output:

[image]

Actual Source Table Data creation query

```
CREATE TABLE student_subject ( student_name, subject_name ) AS
 SELECT 'SMITH', 'CHEMISTRY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'ROBIN', 'PHYSICS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'SAM', 'PHYSICS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'SAM', 'MATH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'JENNY', 'MATH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'JENNY', 'ACCOUNTS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'DON', 'ENGLISH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'DON', 'SPANISH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'RON', 'HISTORY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'JOVAN', 'HISTORY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 -- etc. for an additional 509 more rows
```

See [this dbfiddle for a sample set of 475 rows](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a5997e9f9dabe7b1fbb68d625d7793b7).

Comment: How are the groups defined? Is there a column indicating the group that the student/subject is in? Without having that information, there is no way to split the data in the format you are requesting. For example, why is SMITH/CHEMISTRY in GROUP 1 and not in GROUP 4?

Comment: Please do not delete questions and then re-ask them again a couple of days later.

Comment: @EJEgyed It looks like groups are based on indirect relationships between students. E.g, Robin is taking Physics with Sam and Sam is taking Math with Jenny.  Therefore, all Robin, Sam, and Jenny records are in the same group.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak: that sounds like a good guess. However, for this question to be on topic it would _at the very least_ need to specify this explicitly.

Comment: For future reference: don't try to put 500+ rows into a question. There is simply no need for that, you never need more than a few sample rows that illustrate the larger problem. You can always reference a dbfiddle if you must include a larger set. I've moved your dataset over to one; you only managed to fit in 475 rows so that is what we can use. Or you can use the [dataset from your deleted question](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=173c29936b456e7f258041daec03cba3), which is slightly different and contains 518 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking for a performant solution

If you want *performant*, then forget about SQL.  With your (highly connected) data, there's just no way to pull a `CONNECT BY` trick that isn't going to look at a LOT of extra, unnecessary data.

Here's a simple PL/SQL block that will do it very quickly.  More quickly, by far, I believe, than is possible with pure SQL.  (As usual, I'll happily eat crow on that if it means learning something new...)

This works by finding the records with the lowest `subject_name` from among the rows that have not yet been assigned to a group.  These get the next group number assigned.  Then, we loop through indefinitely looking for rows directly related to rows in the new group and assigning those to the new group.  When we find no more directly related rows, that group is finished and we start the next group.  When we fail to create any new groups, we're finished.

```
-- Add a column to student_subject to hold the group number results
ALTER TABLE student_subject ADD ( group_number NUMBER );

-- Let's time it...
SET TIMING ON

-- Go through and assign group numbers to each record.
-- Doing it iteratively in PL/SQL means we can easily look at each row only once.
BEGIN

  UPDATE student_subject SET group_number = null;
  
  LOOP
    UPDATE student_subject ss
    SET group_number = ( SELECT nvl(max(group_number),0)+1 FROM student_subject ss2 )  -- Assign next group number
    WHERE subject_name = ( SELECT min(subject_name) FROM student_subject ss2 WHERE group_number IS NULL );
    
    EXIT WHEN SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0;  -- done..  all rows have groups now.
  
    LOOP
      UPDATE student_subject ss
      SET group_number = ( SELECT max(group_number) FROM student_subject ss2 )
      WHERE group_number is null
      AND EXISTS ( SELECT 'direct relation' FROM student_subject ss2 WHERE (ss2.subject_name = ss.subject_name OR ss2.student_name = ss.student_name ) AND ss2.group_number = ( SELECT max(group_number) FROM student_subject ss3 ) );
      
      EXIT WHEN SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0;  -- finished group.  move to next group
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;

END;
```

> ```
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
> Elapsed: 00:00:00.128
> ```

You can optimize it further by replacing the `(SELECT...` expressions in the update with PL/SQL variables.  E.g., to keep track of the current group number instead of selecting `MAX()` every time.  I was just lazy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PL/SQL pipelined function:

If you create the types:

```sql
CREATE TYPE ssg_obj AS OBJECT (
  student_name VARCHAR2(100),
  subject_name VARCHAR2(100),
  grp          NUMBER(8,0)
);

CREATE TYPE ssg_tbl AS TABLE OF ssg_obj;
```

Then you can use:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION get_student_subject_groups RETURN ssg_tbl PIPELINED
IS
  TYPE stud_tbl IS TABLE OF STUDENT_SUBJECT.STUDENT_NAME%TYPE;
  TYPE subj_tbl IS TABLE OF STUDENT_SUBJECT.SUBJECT_NAME%TYPE;
  
  ssgs ssg_tbl;
  t_found_students stud_tbl;
  t_found_subjects subj_tbl;
  v_grp            PLS_INTEGER := 0;
  v_min_idx        PLS_INTEGER := 0;
  v_found          BOOLEAN;
  v_match_subj     BOOLEAN;
  v_match_stud     BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  SELECT ssg_obj( student_name, subject_name, 0 )
  BULK COLLECT INTO ssgs
  FROM   student_subject;
  
  LOOP
    v_grp := v_grp + 1;
    v_found := FALSE;

    FOR i IN v_min_idx + 1 .. ssgs.COUNT LOOP
      IF ssgs(i).grp = 0 THEN
        v_min_idx := i;
        ssgs(i).grp := v_grp;
        PIPE ROW( ssgs(i) );
        t_found_students := stud_tbl( ssgs(i).student_name );
        t_found_subjects := subj_tbl( ssgs(i).subject_name );
        v_found := TRUE;
        EXIT;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    EXIT WHEN NOT v_found;
    
    LOOP
      v_found := FALSE;
      FOR i IN v_min_idx + 1 .. ssgs.COUNT LOOP
        IF ssgs(i).grp > 0 THEN
          CONTINUE;
        END IF;
        v_match_subj := ssgs(i).subject_name MEMBER OF t_found_subjects;
        v_match_stud := ssgs(i).student_name MEMBER OF t_found_students;
        IF v_match_subj OR v_match_stud THEN
          ssgs(i).grp := v_grp;
          PIPE ROW( ssgs(i) );
          IF NOT v_match_subj THEN
            t_found_subjects.EXTEND;
            t_found_subjects(t_found_subjects.COUNT) := ssgs(i).subject_name;
            v_found := TRUE;
          END IF;
          IF NOT v_match_stud THEN
            t_found_students.EXTEND;
            t_found_students(t_found_students.COUNT) := ssgs(i).student_name;
            v_found := TRUE;
          END IF;
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
      EXIT WHEN NOT v_found;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE( get_student_subject_groups() )
```

Outputs (for your large sample data):

> ```
> STUDENT_NAME | SUBJECT_NAME                       | GRP
> :----------- | :--------------------------------- | --:
> LIAM         | ACCOUNTING                         | 1
> NOAH         | ACCOUNTING                         | 1
> OLIVER       | ACCOUNTING                         | 1
> WILLIAM      | ACCOUNTING                         | 1
> ELIJAH       | ACCOUNTING                         | 1
> JAMES        | ACCOUNTING                         | 1
> BENJAMIN     | ACCOUNTING                         | 1
> LUCAS        | ACCOUNTING                         | 1
> MASON        | ACCOUNTING                         | 1
> LIAM         | BUSINESS_LAW                       | 1
> NOAH         | BUSINESS_LAW                       | 1
> WILLIAM      | BUSINESS_LAW                       | 1
> ELIJAH       | BUSINESS_LAW                       | 1
> ETHAN        | BUSINESS_LAW                       | 1
> ALEXANDER    | BUSINESS_LAW                       | 1
> HENRY        | BUSINESS_LAW                       | 1
> JACOB        | BUSINESS_LAW                       | 1
> MICHAEL      | BUSINESS_LAW                       | 1
> DANIEL       | BUSINESS_LAW                       | 1
> LOGAN        | BUSINESS_LAW                       | 1
> JACKSON      | BUSINESS_LAW                       | 1
> SEBASTIAN    | BUSINESS_LAW                       | 1
> JACK         | BUSINESS_LAW                       | 1
> AIDEN        | BUSINESS_LAW                       | 1
> OWEN         | BUSINESS_LAW                       | 1
> SAMUEL       | BUSINESS_LAW                       | 1
> MATTHEW      | BUSINESS_LAW                       | 1
> JOSEPH       | BUSINESS_LAW                       | 1
> NOAH         | BUSINESS_MANAGEMENT                | 1
> OLIVER       | BUSINESS_MANAGEMENT                | 1
> WILLIAM      | BUSINESS_MANAGEMENT                | 1
> ELIJAH       | BUSINESS_MANAGEMENT                | 1
> LEVI         | BUSINESS_MANAGEMENT                | 1
> BENJAMIN     | BUSINESS_MANAGEMENT                | 1
> LUCAS        | BUSINESS_MANAGEMENT                | 1
> MATEO        | BUSINESS_MANAGEMENT                | 1
> DAVID        | BUSINESS_MANAGEMENT                | 1
> ETHAN        | BUSINESS_MANAGEMENT                | 1
> ALEXANDER    | BUSINESS_MANAGEMENT                | 1
> HENRY        | BUSINESS_MANAGEMENT                | 1
> JACOB        | BUSINESS_MANAGEMENT                | 1
> MICHAEL      | BUSINESS_MANAGEMENT                | 1
> JOHN         | BUSINESS_MANAGEMENT                | 1
> WYATT        | BUSINESS_MANAGEMENT                | 1
> CARTER       | BUSINESS_MANAGEMENT                | 1
> JULIAN       | BUSINESS_MANAGEMENT                | 1
> LUKE         | BUSINESS_MANAGEMENT                | 1
> GRAYSON      | BUSINESS_MANAGEMENT                | 1
> LIAM         | INTRODUCTION_TO_BUSINESS           | 1
> LUKE         | INTRODUCTION_TO_BUSINESS           | 1
> LIAM         | PERSONAL_FINANCE                   | 1
> NOAH         | PERSONAL_FINANCE                   | 1
> ELIJAH       | PERSONAL_FINANCE                   | 1
> LOGAN        | PERSONAL_FINANCE                   | 1
> LIAM         | APP_DEVELOPMENT                    | 1
> ANTHONY      | APP_DEVELOPMENT                    | 1
> NOAH         | APP_DEVELOPMENT                    | 1
> WILLIAM      | APP_DEVELOPMENT                    | 1
> ELIJAH       | APP_DEVELOPMENT                    | 1
> ETHAN        | APP_DEVELOPMENT                    | 1
> LOGAN        | APP_DEVELOPMENT                    | 1
> DYLAN        | APP_DEVELOPMENT                    | 1
> LIAM         | AUDIO_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> ANTHONY      | AUDIO_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> NOAH         | AUDIO_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> OLIVER       | AUDIO_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> WILLIAM      | AUDIO_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> ELIJAH       | AUDIO_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> JAMES        | AUDIO_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> LEVI         | AUDIO_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> BENJAMIN     | AUDIO_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> LUCAS        | AUDIO_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> MATEO        | AUDIO_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> DAVID        | AUDIO_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> LOGAN        | AUDIO_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> ISAAC        | AUDIO_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> LEO          | AUDIO_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> MASON        | AUDIO_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> LINCOLN      | AUDIO_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> JAYDEN       | AUDIO_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> JAXON        | AUDIO_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> LIAM         | COMPUTER_PROGRAMMING               | 1
> OLIVER       | COMPUTER_PROGRAMMING               | 1
> ASHER        | COMPUTER_PROGRAMMING               | 1
> ELIJAH       | COMPUTER_PROGRAMMING               | 1
> CHRISTOPHER  | COMPUTER_PROGRAMMING               | 1
> LUCAS        | COMPUTER_PROGRAMMING               | 1
> DAVID        | COMPUTER_PROGRAMMING               | 1
> JOSIAH       | COMPUTER_PROGRAMMING               | 1
> DYLAN        | COMPUTER_PROGRAMMING               | 1
> ANDREW       | COMPUTER_PROGRAMMING               | 1
> THOMAS       | COMPUTER_PROGRAMMING               | 1
> WILLIAM      | COMPUTER_REPAIR                    | 1
> LIAM         | FILM_PRODUCTION                    | 1
> JOSHUA       | FILM_PRODUCTION                    | 1
> NOAH         | FILM_PRODUCTION                    | 1
> OLIVER       | FILM_PRODUCTION                    | 1
> ASHER        | FILM_PRODUCTION                    | 1
> ELIJAH       | FILM_PRODUCTION                    | 1
> EZRA         | FILM_PRODUCTION                    | 1
> BENJAMIN     | FILM_PRODUCTION                    | 1
> LUCAS        | FILM_PRODUCTION                    | 1
> MATEO        | FILM_PRODUCTION                    | 1
> DAVID        | FILM_PRODUCTION                    | 1
> HUDSON       | FILM_PRODUCTION                    | 1
> JOSIAH       | FILM_PRODUCTION                    | 1
> DYLAN        | FILM_PRODUCTION                    | 1
> THOMAS       | FILM_PRODUCTION                    | 1
> LIAM         | GRAPHIC_DESIGN                     | 1
> LIAM         | MEDIA_TECHNOLOGY                   | 1
> NOAH         | MEDIA_TECHNOLOGY                   | 1
> DYLAN        | MEDIA_TECHNOLOGY                   | 1
> SEBASTIAN    | MUSIC_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> CHARLES      | MUSIC_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> JOSEPH       | MUSIC_PRODUCTION                   | 1
> LIAM         | TYPING                             | 1
> NOAH         | TYPING                             | 1
> ELIJAH       | TYPING                             | 1
> DYLAN        | TYPING                             | 1
> LIAM         | VIDEO_GAME_DEVELOPMENT             | 1
> NOAH         | VIDEO_GAME_DEVELOPMENT             | 1
> LIAM         | WEB_DESIGN                         | 1
> CALEB        | WEB_DESIGN                         | 1
> ISAIAH       | WEB_DESIGN                         | 1
> WILLIAM      | WEB_DESIGN                         | 1
> ELIJAH       | WEB_DESIGN                         | 1
> ETHAN        | WEB_DESIGN                         | 1
> JACOB        | WEB_DESIGN                         | 1
> LOGAN        | WEB_DESIGN                         | 1
> LIAM         | WORD_PROCESSING                    | 1
> ELIJAH       | AMERICAN_LITERATURE                | 1
> LIAM         | BRITISH_LITERATURE                 | 1
> WILLIAM      | BRITISH_LITERATURE                 | 1
> ELIJAH       | BRITISH_LITERATURE                 | 1
> ETHAN        | BRITISH_LITERATURE                 | 1
> JACOB        | BRITISH_LITERATURE                 | 1
> JACK         | BRITISH_LITERATURE                 | 1
> SAMUEL       | BRITISH_LITERATURE                 | 1
> LIAM         | CONTEMPORARY_LITERATURE            | 1
> ELIJAH       | CONTEMPORARY_LITERATURE            | 1
> LEVI         | CONTEMPORARY_LITERATURE            | 1
> ISAAC        | CONTEMPORARY_LITERATURE            | 1
> LINCOLN      | CONTEMPORARY_LITERATURE            | 1
> JAXON        | CONTEMPORARY_LITERATURE            | 1
> LIAM         | COMMUNICATION_SKILLS               | 1
> NOAH         | COMMUNICATION_SKILLS               | 1
> OLIVER       | COMMUNICATION_SKILLS               | 1
> ELIJAH       | COMMUNICATION_SKILLS               | 1
> BENJAMIN     | COMMUNICATION_SKILLS               | 1
> LUCAS        | COMMUNICATION_SKILLS               | 1
> DAVID        | COMMUNICATION_SKILLS               | 1
> JOHN         | COMMUNICATION_SKILLS               | 1
> LUKE         | COMMUNICATION_SKILLS               | 1
> ANDREW       | COMMUNICATION_SKILLS               | 1
> MAVERICK     | COMMUNICATION_SKILLS               | 1
> LIAM         | DEBATE                             | 1
> NOAH         | DEBATE                             | 1
> LIAM         | ENGLISH_LANGUAGE_AND_COMPOSITION   | 1
> ELIJAH       | ENGLISH_LANGUAGE_AND_COMPOSITION   | 1
> BENJAMIN     | ENGLISH_LANGUAGE_AND_COMPOSITION   | 1
> MASON        | ENGLISH_LANGUAGE_AND_COMPOSITION   | 1
> MATEO        | HUMANITIES                         | 1
> DAVID        | HUMANITIES                         | 1
> ISAAC        | HUMANITIES                         | 1
> LINCOLN      | HUMANITIES                         | 1
> LIAM         | JOURNALISM                         | 1
> COLTON       | JOURNALISM                         | 1
> ELIAS        | JOURNALISM                         | 1
> ELIJAH       | JOURNALISM                         | 1
> LEVI         | JOURNALISM                         | 1
> LIAM         | LITERARY_ANALYSIS                  | 1
> AARON        | LITERARY_ANALYSIS                  | 1
> ELIAS        | LITERARY_ANALYSIS                  | 1
> ELIJAH       | LITERARY_ANALYSIS                  | 1
> LEVI         | LITERARY_ANALYSIS                  | 1
> AARON        | MODERN_LITERATURE                  | 1
> ELIAS        | MODERN_LITERATURE                  | 1
> LEVI         | MODERN_LITERATURE                  | 1
> AARON        | POETRY                             | 1
> ELIAS        | POETRY                             | 1
> LEVI         | POETRY                             | 1
> ELIAS        | POPULAR_LITERATURE                 | 1
> LEVI         | POPULAR_LITERATURE                 | 1
> BENJAMIN     | RHETORIC                           | 1
> ISAAC        | RHETORIC                           | 1
> MASON        | RHETORIC                           | 1
> ELIJAH       | TECHNICAL_WRITING                  | 1
> ANTHONY      | WORKS_OF_SHAKESPEARE               | 1
> ELIJAH       | WORKS_OF_SHAKESPEARE               | 1
> LEVI         | WORKS_OF_SHAKESPEARE               | 1
> LIAM         | WORLD_LITERATURE                   | 1
> ETHAN        | WORLD_LITERATURE                   | 1
> ALEXANDER    | WORLD_LITERATURE                   | 1
> HENRY        | WORLD_LITERATURE                   | 1
> JACOB        | WORLD_LITERATURE                   | 1
> LOGAN        | WRITTEN_AND_ORAL_COMMUNICATION     | 1
> MASON        | WRITTEN_AND_ORAL_COMMUNICATION     | 1
> ELI          | WRITTEN_AND_ORAL_COMMUNICATION     | 1
> LIAM         | CHEMISTRY_OF_FOODS                 | 1
> ANTHONY      | CHEMISTRY_OF_FOODS                 | 1
> LANDON       | CHEMISTRY_OF_FOODS                 | 1
> JONATHAN     | CHEMISTRY_OF_FOODS                 | 1
> NOLAN        | CHEMISTRY_OF_FOODS                 | 1
> NOAH         | CHEMISTRY_OF_FOODS                 | 1
> HUNTER       | CHEMISTRY_OF_FOODS                 | 1
> OLIVER       | CHEMISTRY_OF_FOODS                 | 1
> WILLIAM      | CHEMISTRY_OF_FOODS                 | 1
> ELIJAH       | CHEMISTRY_OF_FOODS                 | 1
> CAMERON      | CHEMISTRY_OF_FOODS                 | 1
> BENJAMIN     | CHEMISTRY_OF_FOODS                 | 1
> LUCAS        | CHEMISTRY_OF_FOODS                 | 1
> LOGAN        | CHEMISTRY_OF_FOODS                 | 1
> MASON        | CHEMISTRY_OF_FOODS                 | 1
> DYLAN        | CHEMISTRY_OF_FOODS                 | 1
> DYLAN        | CPR_TRAINING                       | 1
> LIAM         | CULINARY_ARTS                      | 1
> ELIJAH       | CULINARY_ARTS                      | 1
> GABRIEL      | CULINARY_ARTS                      | 1
> LIAM         | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> SANTIAGO     | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> JEREMIAH     | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> JOSHUA       | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> NOAH         | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> ASHER        | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> ELIJAH       | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> THEODORE     | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> EZRA         | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> LEVI         | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> RYAN         | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> EZEKIEL      | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> ANGEL        | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> JOSIAH       | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> ROMAN        | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> EASTON       | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> LOGAN        | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> MILES        | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> ROBERT       | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> JAMESON      | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> NICHOLAS     | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> GREYSON      | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> COOPER       | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> IAN          | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> MASON        | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> CARSON       | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> AXEL         | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> JAXSON       | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> DOMINIC      | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> LEONARDO     | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> LUCA         | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> AUSTIN       | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> JORDAN       | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> ADAM         | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> XAVIER       | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> JOSE         | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_DEVELOPMENT        | 1
> LIAM         | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_EDUCATION          | 1
> ANTHONY      | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_EDUCATION          | 1
> NOAH         | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_EDUCATION          | 1
> BENJAMIN     | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_EDUCATION          | 1
> MATEO        | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_EDUCATION          | 1
> LOGAN        | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_EDUCATION          | 1
> ISAAC        | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_EDUCATION          | 1
> MASON        | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_EDUCATION          | 1
> JAXON        | EARLY_CHILDHOOD_EDUCATION          | 1
> LIAM         | FAMILY_STUDIES                     | 1
> ELIJAH       | FAMILY_STUDIES                     | 1
> RYAN         | FAMILY_STUDIES                     | 1
> DYLAN        | FAMILY_STUDIES                     | 1
> DYLAN        | FASHION_AND_RETAIL_MERCHANDISING   | 1
> LIAM         | FASHION_CONSTRUCTION               | 1
> SANTIAGO     | FASHION_CONSTRUCTION               | 1
> JEREMIAH     | FASHION_CONSTRUCTION               | 1
> ASHER        | FASHION_CONSTRUCTION               | 1
> ELIJAH       | FASHION_CONSTRUCTION               | 1
> JOSIAH       | FASHION_CONSTRUCTION               | 1
> ROBERT       | FASHION_CONSTRUCTION               | 1
> JAMESON      | FASHION_CONSTRUCTION               | 1
> GREYSON      | FASHION_CONSTRUCTION               | 1
> DYLAN        | FASHION_CONSTRUCTION               | 1
> LIAM         | HOME_ECONOMICS                     | 1
> NOAH         | HOME_ECONOMICS                     | 1
> JACE         | HOME_ECONOMICS                     | 1
> WILLIAM      | HOME_ECONOMICS                     | 1
> ELIJAH       | HOME_ECONOMICS                     | 1
> CONNOR       | HOME_ECONOMICS                     | 1
> LEVI         | HOME_ECONOMICS                     | 1
> BENJAMIN     | HOME_ECONOMICS                     | 1
> EVERETT      | HOME_ECONOMICS                     | 1
> MATEO        | HOME_ECONOMICS                     | 1
> DECLAN       | HOME_ECONOMICS                     | 1
> LOGAN        | HOME_ECONOMICS                     | 1
> ISAAC        | HOME_ECONOMICS                     | 1
> GRAYSON      | HOME_ECONOMICS                     | 1
> EVAN         | HOME_ECONOMICS                     | 1
> MASON        | HOME_ECONOMICS                     | 1
> JAXON        | HOME_ECONOMICS                     | 1
> LIAM         | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> KAYDEN       | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> PARKER       | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> WESLEY       | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> KAI          | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> BRAYDEN      | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> BRYSON       | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> WESTON       | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> NOAH         | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> ELIJAH       | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> BENJAMIN     | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> JOHN         | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> CARTER       | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> LOGAN        | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> JULIAN       | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> ISAAC        | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> MASON        | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> JASON        | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> ELI          | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> EMMETT       | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> SAWYER       | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> SILAS        | INTERIOR_DESIGN                    | 1
> LOGAN        | NUTRITION                          | 1
> BROOKS       | NUTRITION                          | 1
> MICAH        | NUTRITION                          | 1
> DAMIAN       | NUTRITION                          | 1
> MASON        | NUTRITION                          | 1
> HARRISON     | NUTRITION                          | 1
> ELI          | NUTRITION                          | 1
> WAYLON       | NUTRITION                          | 1
> AIDEN        | NUTRITION                          | 1
> AYDEN        | NUTRITION                          | 1
> VINCENT      | NUTRITION                          | 1
> LIAM         | AMERICAN_SIGN_LANGUAGE             | 1
> NOAH         | AMERICAN_SIGN_LANGUAGE             | 1
> ELIJAH       | AMERICAN_SIGN_LANGUAGE             | 1
> BENJAMIN     | AMERICAN_SIGN_LANGUAGE             | 1
> RYDER        | AMERICAN_SIGN_LANGUAGE             | 1
> WYATT        | AMERICAN_SIGN_LANGUAGE             | 1
> MASON        | AMERICAN_SIGN_LANGUAGE             | 1
> LIAM         | ANCIENT_GREEK                      | 1
> NOAH         | ANCIENT_GREEK                      | 1
> ELIJAH       | ANCIENT_GREEK                      | 1
> ETHAN        | ANCIENT_GREEK                      | 1
> LIAM         | ARABIC                             | 1
> NOAH         | ARABIC                             | 1
> LOGAN        | ARABIC                             | 1
> JACKSON      | ARABIC                             | 1
> OWEN         | ARABIC                             | 1
> KINGSTON     | ARABIC                             | 1
> CHARLES      | ARABIC                             | 1
> JOSEPH       | ARABIC                             | 1
> LIAM         | FRENCH                             | 1
> AIDEN        | FRENCH                             | 1
> MATTHEW      | FRENCH                             | 1
> LIAM         | GERMAN                             | 1
> ELIJAH       | GERMAN                             | 1
> MATEO        | GERMAN                             | 1
> GRAYSON      | GERMAN                             | 1
> JAXON        | GERMAN                             | 1
> ELIJAH       | HEBREW                             | 1
> DYLAN        | HEBREW                             | 1
> JAXON        | HEBREW                             | 1
> LIAM         | JAPANESE                           | 1
> LIAM         | KOREAN                             | 1
> ANTHONY      | KOREAN                             | 1
> NOAH         | KOREAN                             | 1
> OLIVER       | KOREAN                             | 1
> ELIJAH       | KOREAN                             | 1
> THEODORE     | KOREAN                             | 1
> EZRA         | KOREAN                             | 1
> LEVI         | KOREAN                             | 1
> RYAN         | KOREAN                             | 1
> BENJAMIN     | KOREAN                             | 1
> LUCAS        | KOREAN                             | 1
> DAVID        | KOREAN                             | 1
> JOHN         | KOREAN                             | 1
> CARTER       | KOREAN                             | 1
> LOGAN        | KOREAN                             | 1
> JULIAN       | KOREAN                             | 1
> JACKSON      | KOREAN                             | 1
> LUKE         | KOREAN                             | 1
> DAMIAN       | KOREAN                             | 1
> ISAAC        | KOREAN                             | 1
> GRAYSON      | KOREAN                             | 1
> GAVIN        | KOREAN                             | 1
> MASON        | KOREAN                             | 1
> JASON        | KOREAN                             | 1
> HARRISON     | KOREAN                             | 1
> EMMETT       | KOREAN                             | 1
> JORDAN       | KOREAN                             | 1
> JAXON        | KOREAN                             | 1
> JOSEPH       | KOREAN                             | 1
> ADAM         | KOREAN                             | 1
> XAVIER       | KOREAN                             | 1
> ELIJAH       | LATIN                              | 1
> MATEO        | LATIN                              | 1
> JAXON        | LATIN                              | 1
> LIAM         | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> LANDON       | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> JONATHAN     | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> NOAH         | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> HUNTER       | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> OLIVER       | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> JACE         | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> WILLIAM      | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> ELIJAH       | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> CAMERON      | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> JAMES        | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> CONNOR       | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> BENJAMIN     | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> LUCAS        | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> EVERETT      | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> MATEO        | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> DAVID        | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> WYATT        | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> LOGAN        | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> ISAAC        | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> GRAYSON      | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> MASON        | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> DYLAN        | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> LINCOLN      | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> JAXON        | PORTUGUESE                         | 1
> RYAN         | RUSSIAN                            | 1
> RYDER        | RUSSIAN                            | 1
> DYLAN        | RUSSIAN                            | 1
> EMMETT       | SPANISH                            | 1
> NICHOLAS     | ALGEBRA_1                          | 1
> LEONARDO     | ALGEBRA_1                          | 1
> SANTIAGO     | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> JEREMIAH     | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> TYLER        | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> NOAH         | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> ASHER        | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> THEODORE     | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> EZRA         | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> LEVI         | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> RYAN         | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> BENJAMIN     | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> EZEKIEL      | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> ANGEL        | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> JOSIAH       | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> ROMAN        | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> EASTON       | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> LOGAN        | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> MILES        | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> ROBERT       | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> JAMESON      | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> NICHOLAS     | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> GREYSON      | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> ISAAC        | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> COOPER       | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> GRAYSON      | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> IAN          | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> MASON        | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> CARSON       | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> AXEL         | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> JAXSON       | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> DOMINIC      | ALGEBRA_2                          | 1
> ISAAC        | CONSUMER_EDUCATION                 | 1
> JAYDEN       | ENTREPRENEURIAL_SKILLS             | 1
> THEODORE     | MARKETING                          | 1
> GABRIEL      | ANIMATION                          | 1
> RYAN         | WEB_PROGRAMMING                    | 1
> GABRIEL      | ENGLISH_LITERATURE_AND_COMPOSITION | 1
> CONNOR       | CPR_TRAINING                       | 1
> BENNETT      | NUTRITION                          | 1
> TYLER        | ALGEBRA_1                          | 1
> NATHAN       | CREATIVE_WRITING                   | 2
> ADRIAN       | CREATIVE_WRITING                   | 2
> CHRISTIAN    | CREATIVE_WRITING                   | 2
> ROWAN        | CHINESE                            | 3
> GEORGE       | CHINESE                            | 3
> LUIS         | CHINESE                            | 3
> CHASE        | CHINESE                            | 3
> COLE         | CHINESE                            | 3
> NATHANIEL    | CHINESE                            | 3
> ZACHARY      | CHINESE                            | 3
> ASHTON       | CHINESE                            | 3
> BRAXTON      | ITALIAN                            | 4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1664c1629a0d3239f54ec1027c1dae02)*

Answer (score 0):

Although you did not specify the classification criteria, after analyzing your output table, we may assume that:

- Group1: one-to-one (student-subject pair);
- Group2: many-to-many;
- Group3: one-to-many;
- Group4: many-to-one;

One way of operationalizing this classification is creating some sort of summary statistics by groups, like the max of counts. So:

1. First, you can count students by subject (creating `student_by_subject` variable).
2. Second, you count subjects by students (`subject_by_student`) and compute the max of `student_by_subject` by student (`max_student`).
3. Third, you compute the max of `subject_by_student` by subjects (`max_subject`);
4. Fourth, you classify the groups accordingly the max counts variables;

This can be done in a single query:

```
create table want as 
select
student_name, subject_name,
case when max_student=1 and max_subject=1 then 1
     when max_student>1 and max_subject>1 then 2
     when max_student=1 and max_subject>1 then 3
     when max_student>1 and max_subject=1 then 4 end as NEW_GROUP
from (select subject_name, student_name, max_student, 
    max(subject_by_student) as max_subject 
    from (select student_name, subject_name, student_by_subject, 
        count(subject_name) as subject_by_student, 
        max(student_by_subject) as max_student
        from (select student_name, subject_name, 
            count(student_name) as student_by_subject
            from student_subject group by subject_name)
        group by student_name)
    group by subject_name)
ORDER by NEW_GROUP;
```

Comment: This fails on many syntax errors. `GROUP` is a keyword and you can't use it without quoting it. You need to prefix the `*` wildcard with a table name/alias. Then you get `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`.

Comment: Hm, ok. Thanks for pointing these errors. I ran it on my machine and it was ok. I am going to correct my answer accordingly to your comments

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=276b4cad3c1ce20a5183812a19063600) This is the start of my debugging .... I stopped on the 3rd error when it wasn't obvious how to correct your solution (and I'm not sure it will actually work on the sample data I've included either where there are 2 groups with exactly the same sizes).

Comment: Well, I modified the code to avoid the errors you mentioned. I managed to obtain the desired output based on the "Example Source Table" provided on the top of the question. This is because the "Target output" is based on it. I did not run on the "actual data" because there is not a desired output based on it.

Comment: Are you running this in Oracle as this is still giving `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ad6c2d180f14c1a7392578c4834d70b7)

Comment: I am running a SQL query on SAS software based on an Oracle server. Maybe that is the reason.... I did try the link you provided and indeed, I got the same error you mentioned. But in my computer it works...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hierarchical query to find the groups:

```sql
SELECT MIN( id ) AS id,
       student_name,
       subject_name
FROM   (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( id ) AS id,
         student_name,
         subject_name
  FROM   (
    SELECT student_name,
           subject_name,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY subject_name, student_name ) AS id,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY subject_name ORDER BY student_name ) AS rn
    FROM   student_subject s
  )
  START WITH rn = 1
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
         PRIOR student_name = student_name
  OR     PRIOR subject_name = subject_name
)
GROUP BY
       student_name,
       subject_name
ORDER BY
       id,
       subject_name,
       student_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE student_subject ( student_name, subject_name ) AS
SELECT 'SMITH', 'CHEMISTRY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ROBIN', 'PHYSICS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SAM', 'PHYSICS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SAM', 'MATH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'JENNY', 'MATH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'JENNY', 'ACCOUNTS' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DON', 'ENGLISH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'DON', 'SPANISH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RON', 'HISTORY' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'JOVAN', 'HISTORY' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID | STUDENT_NAME | SUBJECT_NAME
> -: | :----------- | :-----------
>  1 | JENNY        | ACCOUNTS    
>  1 | JENNY        | MATH        
>  1 | SAM          | MATH        
>  1 | ROBIN        | PHYSICS     
>  1 | SAM          | PHYSICS     
>  2 | SMITH        | CHEMISTRY   
>  3 | DON          | ENGLISH     
>  3 | DON          | SPANISH     
>  4 | JOVAN        | HISTORY     
>  4 | RON          | HISTORY
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=007fe1977025c37b7d26642d7d763e32)*

Comment: I agree -- I love `CONNECT BY` for this kind of thing.  But I think the OP's actual data set is too highly connected for it to perform well in this case.  For example, even ignoring individual students and just looking at relationships between classes, there are over a thousand ways to get from ACCOUNTING to TYPING.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak I know, it works for small samples and that was what the OP posted on their (now-deleted) original version of this question. That's why I've posted a second answer with a PL/SQL pipelined function that does work on large samples.